# How to create a Grid system where each square has an x and y value using visual studios graphics?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My goal is to have a robot use this grid to create a map base off the information it collects from its surroundings. When the robot detects an object the square in front of it turns red. Currently I am stuck on how I can give each square an x and Y value for location purposes. Also when I scroll the screen the block sizes change, can someone provide help with that as well?

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(700, 350, 50, 50);
g.DrawRectangle(myPen, rect); // Draws the Rectangle to the screen
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, 700,350,50,50);`

for (int i = 0; i < 9900; i = i + 50)
{
    rect = new Rectangle(0 + i, 0, 50, 50);
    g.DrawRectangle(myPen, rect);

    for (int j = 0; j < 9900; j = j + 50)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(0 + i, 0 + j, 50, 50);
        g.DrawRectangle(myPen, rect);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look up 2 dimensional arrays. They will allow you to store data in a grid.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to create arrays in visual C?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very quick example of how to do this using a 2d array. It was written in LINQPad, so it may look a little odd, but it should give you some leads.  It allows you to store a map and look up values using x and y coordinates.  You can use the `CellInfo` class to add any extra information about the cell that you need, beyond if it is blocking or not.

Ideally, you would want to wrap the entire array up in your own `Map` class, that abstracts away the details, and gives you a lot of helpful utility functions.  For instance, if your map is extremely large, you may run out of memory.  You could have the `Map` class only load smaller blocks of the map from files on disk as needed, or even make the map wrap around its self easily.

```
void Main()
{
    var map = new CellInfo[10, 10];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            map[x, y] = new CellInfo();
        }
    }

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        map[rnd.Next(0, 10), rnd.Next(0, 10)].IsBlocked = true;
    }

    DrawMap(map).Dump();
}

public Bitmap DrawMap(CellInfo[,] map)
{
    var img = new Bitmap(320, 320, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                var cell = map[x, y];
                Brush brush = cell.IsBlocked ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.White;
                g.FillRectangle(brush, x * 32, y * 32, 31, 31);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x * 32, y * 32, 31, 31);
            }
        }
    }
    return img;
}

public class CellInfo
{
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; } = false;
}
```

It produces the following output (varies each time it is run):

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. would all this be done in visual basics, or would I do this in visual C++?

Comment: It was written in C#, which is the language that your question was tagged with.